# Any (old?) print literature use of 'codecessor'?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, neologisms

Summary: Is there a (possibly old) print literature/use of the word ***codecessor***?

Background: I *intuitively* used the word assuming it exists in peer-reviewed publications first around 2008 only to be told recently that ***codecessor*** does not exist in English dictionaries. Nobody complained and I was told I was understood when I used word. I then searched myself extensively online to come up with the conclusion that mine was the only predominant use of the word. I've found that strange as I naturally assumed back in the day the word existed and never meant to create a neologism or some such.

Since the word appeared in recent print, I've then gone to Wiktionary and added its definition I meant the word to have. The suggested use of it was either as a noun or an adjective. The Wiktionary entry has been called a *[protologism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protologism)* since been [moved](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk%3acodecessor). My definition was:

> *A (technically) co-descendant notion or concept, but not necessarily a close sibling to concepts alike emerged around the same timeframe from the same or similar predecessor concept(s).*
>
> **The X is based in part on its Y predecessors and codecessors, such as Z, A, B, and C.**

(Other terms I would use would be *co-descendant* or *co-successor*, but they didn't end up being used.)

Thus the main question if anyone here has ever come across ***codecessor*** elsewhere, such as older print literature, and if yes, what is the reference and a possible definition.

Comment: Interestingly, although *[codecessor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Mokhov/codecessor)* has been incarcerated in a wiktionary talk page, its plural *[codecessors](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/codecessors)* remains at large.

Comment: @jwpat7 codecessor was [userfied to me](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Mokhov/codecessor); the Talk page is the RfV discussion. However, you are right, the dangling plural is still there in the mainspace... I guess it will be incarcerated next.

Comment: @jwpat7 I have requested the move of *codecessors* and it was done until, if ever, the term gains traction and wider use or more past use is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither *OED 1* nor Google Books records the term, and the only hits on Google appear to derive from your own use. Go ahead and copyright it.

I have to say, though, that it is not a ‘natural’ coinage. *Predecessor* derives from L decedere meaning “withdraw, retire, go away”: your predecessor originally meant the guy who held your office before you. Consequently, in the ordinary course of derivation a “codecessor” would be not a cosuccessor with you of a previous officeholder but someone who retired at the same time as the previous officeholder, his contemporary.

But, hey, you’re Humpty Dumpty, it’s your word, you get to make it mean whatever you want; and it seems you’ve got other folks understanding it, so you’re home free.

Comment: Copyright it? I think I'd rather copyleft it :)

Comment: PS: I should have added that I did search Google Books, OED 1, etc. myself.

Comment: Words are not copyrightable. At most, they can be trademarks.